# Is there any reason that a one would use .propertyName to access a property vs. ["propertyName"] when accessing a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Say I have an array of objects like this:

```
function obj (name) {
    this.name = name
}
let x = {
    'foo': new obj('foo');
    'bar': new obj('bar');
}
```

Is there an advantage to using `x['foo'].name` over `x['foo']['name]`?

I recognize that `[]` notation is a lot more versatile when it comes to adding things to an object or when looping through an object with `for` so is there any reason besides ease of use that one would choose to access it with `.`? Does it provide a speed increase or is it just for readability?

Comment: `.propertyName` is not quite the same a `[propertyName]` ... it's actually the same as `['propertyName']`

Comment: That’s effectively what I meant

Comment: `[] notation is a lot more versatile when it comes to adding things to an object` - not really ... `[]` is useful if the property name contains spaces, or symbols like -, * + etc

Comment: If anything, dot notation is faster.

Comment: .propertyName is easier to read, it's the standard way of doing so. But if you are iterating through the properties of an object, you have to use the other method.

Comment: Sorry, I was addressing the title of the question, which is clearly not representative of the question

Comment: In normal JavaScript it’s equivalent. It’s important only in terms of readability/style.  But in typed variants of JavaScript, like TypeScript and Closure, the brackets are often treated as a dynamic expression while the dotted form is treated like a static property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x.y is generally preferred as it is faster to write / nicer to use.

x["y"] is useful with obscure keys such as "d-2", "1.2" or other non-ascii characters.

In the first case, you can't do x.d-2 as this becomes `x.d - 2` (completely different).

Comment: The brackets notation also allows for dynamic access to properties. Trivial example: you have `properties = ["name", "age", "id"]` and then you do `properties.forEach( property => console.log(obj[property]) )`